# Docusaurus 2 - Sticky Announcement Banner

Tags: docusaurus

Is it possible to "sticky" the Announcement Banner above the header on scroll? And if so, how? I have a need to have a banner always be shown but it's not a header either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easy way, although it will be bellow the header. But after scrolling down it will sticky at the top.

**1) Before scrolling down:**
[image: Before scrolling down]

**2) After scrolling down:**
[image: After scrolling down]

---

How to:

**0)** Make sure that you set the custom theme in your `docusaurus.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
[…]
  presets: [
  [
      '@docusaurus/preset-classic',
      […]    
      theme: {
          customCss: require.resolve('./src/css/custom.css'),
      },
  ],
[…]
```

**1)** Add this `style` to your `custom.css` — it is an example, modify to attend your needs:

```
div.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

**2)** Add the div container to your `markdown` file — this div will receive the ads-content, so modify at your will:

```
# Lorem Ipsum

<div className="sticky"></div>

Lorem Ipsum is simply…
```